# How to get the most power efficiency of solar panels?

Tags: power-supply, current

I am doing a project about solar panels and I will like to know what is the best way to connect 2 small solar panels and get a high power efficiency?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Point them at the sun. Buy a auto-tracker to keep them pointed at the sun all day.

Comment: To add to @Sparky256 comment, use a maximum power-point tracking circuit, locate yourself as optimally as possible: the highest annual mean irradiance of \$300\: {\text{W}\over \text{m}^2}\$ can be found in the Red Sea; but in orbit over Earth and pointing at the sun this is over \$1300\: {\text{W}\over \text{m}^2}\$. And then there are research projects claiming high efficiency for solar cells and other projects focusing the sun's energy from a large area onto small spots. Do your own research, though, and make this project your own and about your learning process.

Comment: You’d think if we were to figure out the maximum amount of efficiency with solar panels, we would be using green energy all over the planet by now. I guess it’s not as easy as we think it is.

Comment: Mount them outside the atmosphere...

Comment: @KingDuken, Getting the best possible efficiency from a given PV cell is a solved problem.  Designing new, _more_ efficient PV cells is ongoing work.  And, in case you hadn't noticed, the manufacture and installation of grid-tied PV systems is a fast-growing business.

Comment: Several answers mention [Maximum Power Point Tracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_point_tracking), but none explain it:  If you short out a PV cell, you get zero volts at some number of amps.  Zero volts == zero power.  If you disconnect a PV cell, you get the most possible volts, but no current.  No current == no power.  Somewhere in between is an optimum point that maximizes the power (volts time amps).  The "tracking" is because that optimum point _changes_ as the light level changes.  An MPPT charge controller varies the load to get the optimal voltage and current.

Answer (score 1):

How to use solar panels efficiently.

a) Get all the light on them you can.

Point them at the sun.
Be outdoors.
Keep them clean.
Report their generation levels when the sun is shining, rather than when it's cloudy.

b) Load them with the correct load

Use a MPPT (Maximum Power Point Tracking) converter. This adjusts the amount of current it takes from the panel, and measures how much power it's drawing. It then makes a small adjustment, measures again, and keeps which of the two settings produced the most power. It then keeps this up indefinitely.

As the panels' output varies during the day, it will track to maximise the amount of power it's drawing, as long as it has somewhere to send the power to. Common power sinks tend to be a battery in need of charging, an inverter back-feeding the mains, or maybe a water heater or bunch of light bulbs for experimental purposes.

The power sink must be capable of absorbing the maximum power the panel+MPPT can generate, otherwise damage could occur, or the MPPT will adjust down giving you pessimistic metered power.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple solar cells the best efficiency you can get is by implementing a maximum power point tracking (MPPT) on a single cell level and then connect the output to a common bus.

This allows power optimization of each individual cell instead of a series string of cells - which can have multiple local power maxima and that can confuse simple algorithms.

[image: Multiple maximums in a partially shaded module]

Picture taken from [here](http://www.avdweb.nl/dummy/6-fietsroute-maastricht-vise/detail/73-maastricht-vise-005.html?tmpl=component) - actually the page is a good read.

If you convert that image into power (what you usually are interested in):
[image]

In this case the tracking algorithm might get stuck to one of the lower local maxima. Some algorithms are doing a full scan of the curve every now and then to prevent this.

It also allows for higher efficiency if your array gets partial shade as the shaded cell will work on its own MPP and the non-shaded will do the same.

Depending on the size of your solar cells implementing a MPPT might use too much of the power, but in some of my research I did, even a very small cell can get gains by up to 20 % energy harvested compared to no MPPT.